# unsigned/signed short/int conversion

Tags: c++, c

I'm studying signed-unsigned integer conversions and I came to these conclusions, can someone tell me if this is correct please

```
unsigned short var = -65537u;
```

Steps:

- 65537u (implicitly converted to unsigned int)

Binary representation: 
0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0001

- -65537u

Binary representation: 1111 1111 1111 1110 1111 1111 1111 1111

- Truncated to short

Binary representation: 1111 1111 1111 1111

- read as an unsigned short: 65535

---

The same should apply for the following cases:

```
unsigned short var = -65541u;
```

- 65541u (unsigned int)

0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0101

- -65541u

1111 1111 1111 1110 1111 1111 1111 1011

- Truncated to short

1111 1111 1111 1011

- read as an unsigned short: 65531

---

```
unsigned short var = -5u;
```

- 5u (unsigned int)

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101

- -5u

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011

- Truncated to short

1111 1111 1111 1011

- read as an unsigned short: 65531

Comment: The languages have only minimum sizes for int and short (they might be the same size, or not) as well as allowing several different binary representations. You have made some very specific assumptions that are not universally valid. For example `5` and `-5` might differ only in the sign bit.

Comment: @BoPersson It is true that `-5` may not be represented in 2's complement, but this is not relevant to the question, as the question does not involve **any** negative number. In this question, unary negation is only applied to unsigned types. For instance `-65537u` is parsed as `-(65537u)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct for the usual platforms where `short` is 16 bits and `int` is 32 bits.

For some platforms, the constant `65537` may not fit in an `unsigned int`, but if that is the case, `65537u` will be typed as a larger unsigned type. The list of types that are tried can be found in section 6.4.4.1:5 of the C99 standard. In C99 it will at least fit in an `unsigned long`, which is guaranteed by the standard to allow values that large.

The reasoning remains much of the same if that happens, until the conversion back to `unsigned short` for the assignment.

Conversely, `unsigned short` is allowed by the C99 standard to hold more than 16 bits. In this case `var` receives `USHRT_MAX-65536` for your first example and similarly for the other ones.

Comment: Thanks, I aim to have strong C/C++ basis foundations

Answer (score 0):

The size of short is implementation dependant - not 16bit. 16bit is the minimum size.

Similairly the size of an int may only be 16bit also.

Comment: You are right in that the question is asked in the context of 16-bit `short`, 32-bit `int` types, and should say so explicitly, but that's a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: It is an answer. He is possibly wrong about what the truncation yield.